# Is this JavascriptClosure usecase?

Tags: javascript, arrays, closures

I have perhaps beginner Javascript question:

```
var countries = [
    "Bangladesh", "Germany", "Pakistan"];


function testexistence(arr, input) {

    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (arr[i] != input) {
            alert("not exist");
            arr.push(input);
            break;
        } else {
            alert("already exist ");
        }
    }

}

testexistence(countries, "UK");
testexistence(countries, "Pakistan");
testexistence(countries, "UK");
```

What I expect is: when I call the function again for 'UK' it shows me "already exist"; but that is not happening. I don't wanna play with "prototype"  or define my own one.I just need one line solution.

I have a use case in my code, where I have to insert a new value in array and in the next loops I have to check that value; but I am ending up inserting an existing value...

why I am ending up inserting the existing value and why this check `(arr[i] != input)` is failing ?

***Please also explain, why the above code is not working as desired***

Comment: You should probably push input, not "UK" every time. Is it not working?

Comment: `testexistence` is not a good name for the function. How about `pushIfUnique` or `pushUnique`?

Answer (score 3):

You need to search the entire array before you can decide it doesnt exist.

```
function testexistence(arr, input) {
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (arr[i] === input) {
            alert("already exists");
            return; // halt the search by returning
        }
    }

    // If we're here, we never returned inside the loop, so it wasn't found.
    arr.push(input);
    alert("did not exist, now it does");
}
```

---

Instead of `testexistence`, I'd probably name your function `addUnique` or something.

Comment: Since you're provide a solution, you should probably push `input`, not `UK`.

Comment: @cfs: Heh, didn't even notice that. Just copied and pasted the code. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
function testexistence(arr, input) {
    if (!~arr.indexOf(input)) {
        arr.push(input);
    }
}
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/L9NhU/

Note that `Array.indexOf` isn't available in older browsers, so you can use a polyfill (or keep your current looping). Here's the MDN docs for it, which includes a polyfill: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf

Comment: Seems like his code wants to add something that isn't there when tested. Needs modification :D

Comment: why did you use ~ for your "is in array?" test? is it more efficient than `return (arr.indexOf(input) != -1)`?

Comment: @andytuba it's a shorter way to test booleans. [`!~` checks for `-1`](http://www.javascriptturnsmeon.com/the-tilde-operator-in-javascript/)

Comment: @andytuba It's a bitwise operator where the result is `0` **only** for `-1` (the item wasn't found). So `!~` is true when the item wasn't found in the array. It's quicker because it bitwise operations are fast and comparison checks are faster when you're checking for truthyness than comparing two items

Answer (score 1):

For one, it's **not in any way a closure**.

Anyways, here's [the one-liner you wanted](http://jsfiddle.net/L9NhU/1/), a modification of [Ian's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16151825/575527)

```
function testexistence(arr, input) {
  (!~arr.indexOf(input)) && arr.push(input);
}
```

We use a couple of things:

- `Array.indexOf` searches the array for the first match of what you passed, and returns a zero-based value if existing, or a `-1` if non-existing.
- `!~` is a special case here, where we test for `-1`. A value `~x` is equal to `-(x+1)`, which makes `-1` a `0` (falsy) and all others non-zero (truthy). Adding `!` into the mix makes `-1` a truthy value and others falsy.
- `&&` evaluates both its sides. If the left is "truthy", then the right is evaluated, otherwise it doesn't. It's also known as the "guard operator"

Comment: You should avoid using `&&` in this way. As JavaScript Creator Brendan Eich pointed out on his blog, [it's an *abusage*](http://brendaneich.com/2012/04/the-infernal-semicolon/). Best to use an actual `if-statement` instead. You won't use more chars either; simply turn the `&&` into `if` and put it on the other side of the condition.

Answer (score 0):

You need to try something like this

```
var countries = ["london", "germany", "france"];


function testexistence(arr, input) {
   var isExists = false;

    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (arr[i] == input) {
            isExists = true;
        }         
    }

    if(!isExists)
    {
        alert("Not Exists");
        arr.push(input);
    }
    else
    {
        alert("Exists");
    }
}

testexistence(countries, "UK");
testexistence(countries, "london");
testexistence(countries, "UK");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this instead of yours:

```
function testexistence(arr, input) {

    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (arr[i] == input) {
            alert("already exist ");
            return;
        }
    }

    //if the if part would not work, you pass to here
    alert("not exist");
    arr.push(item);
}
```